# How does EIP 150 change the call depth attack?

Tags: gas, evm, eip150

It seems that [EIP-150](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/150) introduced a more expensive gas based restriction on the call stack and completely removed the previous 1024 hard stack limit. Is this true? It seems it took cues from [EIP-90](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/90) & [EIP-114](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/114), but not entirely sure what was implemented.

How does the new gas based limit work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The previous limit has not been removed, it's just become practically unreachable.

With the new rules, the call cannot consume more than 63/64 of the gas of the parent. So if your gas is X, then `N` `CALL`s in, it will be max `X * (63/64)^n`.

And to be correct, the gas is even less than that, since 63/64 is defined as "all but one 64th" of N as N - floor(N / 64), so there's also a factor of flooring to integers which has an effect. Also, the actual `CALL` cost and `PUSH` operations required will also reduce the practical limit.

From the [EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/150):

> Note that with the given parameters, the de-facto maximum call stack depth is limited to ~340 (down from ~1024), mitigating the harm caused by any further potential quadratic-complexity DoS attacks that rely on calls.

Comment: Thanks @mhswende! So the hard limit is still in there. It looks it will take a substantially high gas limit to even come close to 1024 right?

Comment: Yes. I've seen a number that Vitalik calculated, but I'm not sure where to find it now. It's orders of magnitude above the limits used so far.