# Are solidity contracts still vulnerable to callstack exploits?

Tags: solidity, call-depth-attacks, vulnerability

I was reading the paper at http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~loiluu/papers/oyente.pdf and it mentions callstack bugs where since the call depth is set at 1024, a contract may be able to call itself 1023 times, then call a function in a contract and that will fail, eg:

```
  function CallstackExploit (int counter) {
    if (counter < 1023) {
        if (counter > 0) {
            self.CallstackExploit.gas(msg.gas-2000)(counter+1);
        } else {
            self.CallstackExploit(counter+1);
        }
    } else {
        // finally call a function in another contract after calling self.CallstackExploit 1023 times
    }
  }
```

Was this fixed? Executing the above function with any value of int < 1023 I get a "bad instruction" error on etherscan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attack was eliminated for all practical purposes by [EIP 150](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-150.md), which [was implemented in October, 2016](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/).

For details see [How does EIP 150 change the call depth attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/how-does-eip-150-change-the-call-depth-attack)