# Calling multiple smart contracts -- how deep can it go?

Tags: contract-invocation

How many nested calls can an Ethereum transaction do?

Can Smart Contract A call Smart Contract B, then Smart Contract C and so on with only one call through Smart Contract A, and is there a limit to this chain of calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ethereum allows up to 1024 nested calls as specified in the [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf).

The definition of the `CALL` opcode presented below, specifies this limit.
[image]
[image]

Some recent changes to the limit of the gas allowed to be consumed by nested calls have reduced the practical limit of call depth to around 340. See: [How does EIP 150 change the call depth attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/how-does-eip-150-change-the-call-depth-attack)

The change is due to the fact that the max amount of gas that may be used by a nested call is `ceil(63/64 * remaining_gas)`.

Comment: Thanks Thorkil! This means Smart Contract 1 can call up to Smart Contract 1024?

Comment: In theory yes. But it seems that some recent changes has made it impossible to make more than 340 nested calls due to gas limits:
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/150 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/how-does-eip-150-change-the-call-depth-attack